# Hide column in sql query output

Tags: sql, hide

```
SELECT 
    MProduct.ProductCode, MProduct.ProductName, COUNT(*) AS Ranges
FROM 
    TProblem 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    MProduct ON TProblem.ProductCode = MProduct.ProductCode 
GROUP BY  
    MProduct.ProductCode, MProduct.ProductName 
ORDER BY 
    Ranges DESC
```

This is my query but I want to hide the `Ranges` column from output

Comment: Well if you want to hide it - then **don't list it** in the `SELECT` list of columns!

Comment: actually its is imp so i dont want to show it

Answer (score 3):

To maintain the order of your results, just move the count from your select to the order by:

```
SELECT 
    MProduct.ProductCode, MProduct.ProductName
FROM 
    TProblem 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    MProduct ON TProblem.ProductCode = MProduct.ProductCode 
GROUP BY  
    MProduct.ProductCode, MProduct.ProductName 
ORDER BY 
    count(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand where @marc_s is coming from. It looks like you are trying to get a list of DISTINCT rows

```
SELECT ProductCode, ProductName
FROM
(
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
    MProduct.ProductCode, MProduct.ProductName, COUNT(*) AS Ranges
FROM 
    TProblem 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    MProduct ON TProblem.ProductCode = MProduct.ProductCode 
GROUP BY  
    MProduct.ProductCode, MProduct.ProductName 
ORDER BY 
    Ranges DESC
) AS DATA
```

Or alternatively

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MProduct.ProductCode, MProduct.ProductName
FROM 
    TProblem 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    MProduct ON TProblem.ProductCode = MProduct.ProductCode 
    MProduct.ProductCode, MProduct.ProductName
```

Comment: hey i am getting the follwing error for this query .The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: The inner query requires a TOP 100 PERCENT  to cater for ORDER BY. Answer has been updated. This answer also assumes you are using SQL Server

Comment: The multi-part identifier "MProduct.ProductName" could not be bound. this is next error